# How to re-project only one band from a hdf?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, hdf

I have this file which contains:

```
gdalinfo product.hdf
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
calendar=standard
center=gsfc
Subdatasets:  
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

as you can see, there are 24 bands What I need is just to extract the first band  of the sub-dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by combining gdalwarp and gdal_translate:

```
gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs epsg:3410 -tr 25000 25000 HDF4_SDS:UNKOWN:"product1.hdf":5 warped.tif
gdal_translate -b 1 warped.tif band1.tif
```

If you want all 24 bands separately, you can write a batch file with this content (on Linux it might be different):

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,24) DO gdal_translate -b %%G warped.tif %%G.tif
```